# How to extract specific data from XML data

Tags: c#, xml, parsing, csv

I am using the following code snippet to parse and convert some XML data to CSV. I can convert the entire XML data and dump it into a file, however my requirements have changed and now I'm confused.

```
public void xmlToCSVfiltered(string p, int e)
        {                 
            string all_lines1 = File.ReadAllText(p);

            all_lines1 = "<Root>" + all_lines1 + "</Root>";
            XmlDocument doc_all = new XmlDocument();
            doc_all.LoadXml(all_lines1);
            StreamWriter write_all = new StreamWriter(FILENAME2);
            XmlNodeList rows_all = doc_all.GetElementsByTagName("XML");

            List<string[]> filtered = new List<string[]>();

            foreach (XmlNode rowtemp in rows_all)
            {
                List<string> children_all = new List<string>();
                foreach (XmlNode childtemp in rowtemp.ChildNodes)
                {
                    children_all.Add(Regex.Replace(childtemp.InnerText, "\\s+", " "));     // <------- Fixed the Bug , Advisories dont span          
                }  
                string.Join(",", children_all.ToArray());

                //write_all.WriteLine(string.Join(",", children_all.ToArray()));

                if (children_all.Contains(e.toString()))
                {
                    filtered.Add(children_all.ToArray());
                    write_all.WriteLine(children_all);
                }
            }
            write_all.Flush();
            write_all.Close();

            foreach (var res in filtered)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", res));
            }
        }
```

My input looks something like the following... My objective now is to only convert those "events" and compile into a CSV which have a certain number. Lets say, for example, I only want to convert to CSV those events who's 2nd data value under element `<EVENT>` is 4627. It would only convert those events and in the case of the input below, both mentioned below.

```
<XML><HEADER>1.0,770162,20121009133435,3,</HEADER>20121009133435,721,5,1,0,0,0,00:00,00:00,<EVENT>00032134826064957,4627,</EVENT><DRUG>1,1872161156,7,0,10000</DRUG><DOSE>1,0,5000000,0,10000000,0</DOSE><CAREAREA>1 </CAREAREA><ENCOUNTER></ENCOUNTER><ADVISORY>Keep it simple or spell
        tham ALL out. For some reason 
        that is not the case
        please press the on button 
        when trying to activate
        device codes also available on
    list</ADVISORY><CAREGIVER></CAREGIVER><PATIENT></PATIENT><LOCATION>20121009133435,00-1d-71-0a-71-80,-66</LOCATION><ROUTE></ROUTE><SITE></SITE><POWER>0,50</POWER></XML> 
<XML><HEADER>2.0,773162,20121009133435,3,</HEADER>20121004133435,761,5,1,0,0,0,00:00,00:00,<EVENT>00032134826064957,4627,</EVENT><DRUG>1,18735166156,7,0,10000</DRUG><DOSE>1,0,5000000,0,10000000,0</DOSE><CAREAREA>1 </CAREAREA><ENCOUNTER></ENCOUNTER><ADVISORY>Keep it simple or spell
        tham ALL out. For some reason 
        that is not the case
        please press the on button 
        when trying to activate
        device codes also available on
    list</ADVISORY><CAREGIVER></CAREGIVER><PATIENT></PATIENT><LOCATION>20121009133435,00-1d-71-0a-71-80,-66</LOCATION><ROUTE></ROUTE><SITE></SITE><POWER>0,50</POWER></XML> 

.. goes on
```

What my approach has been so far is to convert everything to CSV and store it in some sort of data structure and then query that data structure line by line and look if that number exists and if yes, write it to a file line by line. My function takes the path of the XML file and the number we are looking for in the XML data as parameters. I'm new to C# and I cannot understand how I would go about changing my function above. Any help will be appreciated!

**EDIT:**

Sample Input:

```
<XML><HEADER>1.0,770162,20121009133435,3,</HEADER>20121009133435,721,5,1,0,0,0,00:00,00:00,<EVENT>00032134826064957,4627,</EVENT><DRUG>1,1872161156,7,0,10000</DRUG><DOSE>1,0,5000000,0,10000000,0</DOSE><CAREAREA>1 </CAREAREA><ENCOUNTER></ENCOUNTER><ADVISORY>Keep it simple or spell
    tham ALL out. For some reason 
    that is not the case
    please press the on button 
    when trying to activate
    device codes also available on
list</ADVISORY><CAREGIVER></CAREGIVER><PATIENT></PATIENT><LOCATION>20121009133435,00-1d-71-0a- 

    <XML><HEADER>1.0,770162,20121009133435,3,</HEADER>20121009133435,721,5,1,0,0,0,00:00,00:00,<EVENT>00032134826064957,4623,</EVENT><DRUG>1,1872161156,7,0,10000</DRUG><DOSE>1,0,5000000,0,10000000,0</DOSE><CAREAREA>1 </CAREAREA><ENCOUNTER></ENCOUNTER><ADVISORY>Keep it simple or spell
        tham ALL out. For some reason 
        that is not the case
        please press the on button 
        when trying to activate
        device codes also available on
    list</ADVISORY><CAREGIVER></CAREGIVER><PATIENT></PATIENT><LOCATION>20121009133435,00-1d-71-0a-
```

Required Output:

```
1.0,770162,20121009133435,3,,20121009133435,721,5,1,0,0,0,00:00,00:00,,00032134 26064957,4627,1,,1872161156,7,0,10000,1,0,5000000,0,10000000,0,1 ,,Keep it simple or spell
    tham ALL out. For some reason 
    that is not the case
    please press the on button 
    when trying to activate
    device codes also available on
list,,,20121009133435,00-1d-71-0a-71-80,-66,,,0,50
```

The above will be the case if I call `xmlToCSVfiltered(file, 4627);`
Also note that, the output will be a single horizontal line as in CSV files but I can't really format it here for it to look like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed XmlDocumnet to XDocument so I can use Xml Linq.  I also for testing used a StringReader to read the string instead of reading from a file.  You can convert code back to your original File.ReadAlltext.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.IO;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME2 = @"c:\temp\test.txt";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string input = 
            "<XML><HEADER>1.0,770162,20121009133435,3,</HEADER>20121009133435,721,5,1,0,0,0,00:00,00:00,<EVENT>00032134826064957,4627,</EVENT><DRUG>1,1872161156,7,0,10000</DRUG><DOSE>1,0,5000000,0,10000000,0</DOSE><CAREAREA>1 </CAREAREA><ENCOUNTER></ENCOUNTER><ADVISORY>Keep it simple or spell\n" +
                    "tham ALL out. For some reason \n" +
                    "that is not the case\n" +
                    "please press the on button\n" + 
                    "when trying to activate\n" +
                    "device codes also available on\n" +
                "list</ADVISORY><CAREGIVER></CAREGIVER><PATIENT></PATIENT><LOCATION>20121009133435,00-1d-71-0a-71-80,-66</LOCATION><ROUTE></ROUTE><SITE></SITE><POWER>0,50</POWER></XML>\n" + 
            "<XML><HEADER>2.0,773162,20121009133435,3,</HEADER>20121004133435,761,5,1,0,0,0,00:00,00:00,<EVENT>00032134826064957,4627,</EVENT><DRUG>1,18735166156,7,0,10000</DRUG><DOSE>1,0,5000000,0,10000000,0</DOSE><CAREAREA>1 </CAREAREA><ENCOUNTER></ENCOUNTER><ADVISORY>Keep it simple or spell\n" +
                    "tham ALL out. For some reason\n" + 
                    "that is not the case\n" +
                    "please press the on button\n" + 
                    "when trying to activate\n" +
                   "device codes also available on\n" +
                "list</ADVISORY><CAREGIVER></CAREGIVER><PATIENT></PATIENT><LOCATION>20121009133435,00-1d-71-0a-71-80,-66</LOCATION><ROUTE></ROUTE><SITE></SITE><POWER>0,50</POWER></XML>\n";

            xmlToCSVfiltered(input, 4627); 

        }
        static public void xmlToCSVfiltered(string p, int e)
        {
            //string all_lines1 = File.ReadAllText(p);
            StringReader reader = new StringReader(p);
            string all_lines1 = reader.ReadToEnd();

            all_lines1 = "<Root>" + all_lines1 + "</Root>";
            XDocument doc_all = XDocument.Parse(all_lines1);
            StreamWriter write_all = new StreamWriter(FILENAME2);
            List<XElement> rows_all = doc_all.Descendants("XML").Where(x => x.Element("EVENT").Value.Split(new char[] {','}).Skip(1).Take(1).FirstOrDefault() == e.ToString()).ToList();

            List<string[]> filtered = new List<string[]>();

            foreach (XElement rowtemp in rows_all)
            {
                List<string> children_all = new List<string>();
                foreach (XElement childtemp in rowtemp.Elements())
                {
                    children_all.Add(Regex.Replace(childtemp.Value, "\\s+", " "));     // <------- Fixed the Bug , Advisories dont span          
                }
                string.Join(",", children_all.ToArray());

                //write_all.WriteLine(string.Join(",", children_all.ToArray()));

                if (children_all.Contains(e.ToString()))
                {
                    filtered.Add(children_all.ToArray());
                    write_all.WriteLine(children_all);
                }
            }
            write_all.Flush();
            write_all.Close();

            foreach (var res in filtered)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", res));
            }
        }
    }
}
​
```

Comment: Tried your approach but I'm getting blank output files.

Comment: Are you getting the same?

Comment: I updated the code.  Make sure you use latest.  I was a little dyslexic and typed  4267 instead of 4627.

Comment: Yea, I changed that and tried. Still getting blank output files.

Comment: Check my edit, I've added my exact function as of now.. I can't pinpoint where it goes wrong. From my print statements, I can see that it doesn't enter the bottom IF loop.

Comment: You don't need that section.  I put the filter in the XML part of the code.  I verified that the filter worked for variable 'rows_all' and never checked any of the code below that line.  Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

I have made some assumptions since it was not clear to me from the question

**Assumptions**

1. I am assuming you know that you need to check node event and you need to second position element from there.

2. You know the delimiter between the values in node. for eg. ',' here in events

```
    public void xmlToCSVfiltered(string p, int e, string nodeName, char delimiter)
    {
        //get the xml node
        XDocument xml = XDocument.Load(p);

        //get the required node. I am assuming you would know. For eg. Event Node
        var requiredNode = xml.Descendants(nodeName);

        foreach (var node in requiredNode)
        {
            if (node == null)
                continue;

            //Also here, I am assuming you have the delimiter knowledge.
            var valueSplit = node.Value.Split(delimiter);

            foreach (var value in valueSplit)
            {
                if (value == e.ToString())
                {
                    AddToCSV();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: One main reason this is not going to work for me is that, the position number is not a constant. In some cases, the position number for the number I'm looking for could be 10 and in another case it could be 15. Ultimately the goal is to check every number between commas and output the lines which have that value.